error TS2322: Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

I have an @Input() property with the data type string | string[]. Before upgrading to Angular 16, it was working fine, but after I upgraded to Angular 16, I started getting this error. I'm not sure where I went wrong. I have a component that has an input property as shown below:
let call this MyComponent 
@Input() info: string | string[];

Somewhere in my app, I am using this component and passing the info value:
// Case #1
// value = 'something in ts file'
<my-component [info]="value">

// Case #2
// arrayValue = ['a', 'b', 'c']
<my-component [info]="arrayValue">

I'm not sure what is wrong. I have already tried changing the type like this:
export type stringOrArray = string | string[];

However, I got the same error.

Can you share the code which leads to the mentioned compilation error? Pretty sure you are trying to assign it to a variable which is string type. It can't accept the string[] value.

i have updated the use cases above. kindly can you check where i might be wrong.

And then how is info consumed in the component? Is there an assignment sth = someFunction(this.info), is it used in the template <some-child someInput="info">?

Since there are two possible types string and string[] we need to explicitly tell typescript that the value you are assigning is of which type
this.test = <string>this.info;

Full code:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrl: './child.component.css',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() info!: string | string[];
  test: string = '';
  ngOnInit() {
    if(typeof this.info === 'string') {
        this.test = this.info;
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

But if info is declared as string | string[], should you simply assert it's a string without checking? There must be a reason for this type declaration.

@mbojko added type check

@NarenMurali thank you for the answer i tried to resolve it but got the same error
this code lies in the base class and the child component extends from it.
`@Directive()
export abstract class BaseFilterComponent {
@Input()
info!: string | string[];
}
`

@awaisnawaz please replicate the issue in the provided stackblitz and share back!

thank you by doing this error is resolved, using never as datatype and then check typing can resolve the issue.

Type checking must be performed to determine whether our variable is of type string or string[]. Once we're certain it's a string with typeof this.info === 'string', we can then pass its value to another variable that accepts ONLY strings.
@NarenMurali already mentioned it in answer, but I think he overthought the example and didn't focus on the essence, so I'm leaving this here:
let message: string | string[] = 'Example'
let result: string = ''

if (typeof message === 'string') {
  // the 'message' variable is a string, so I can pass it as a string
  result = message // it safely receives a string
}
else {
  // the 'message' variable is not a string, so I concatenated the elements of the array into a string
  result = message.split(' ') // message is definitely an array, so split() will work
}

